# Bootstrap collapse and padding issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I'm using the collapse with transitions. The code below works but because I have 10px padding in my stylesheet I see the div collapse but stop 10px before it should and then vanish. The reverse is true on expanding as the div expands to 10px greater than it should before snapping back to the correct size.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="box-content collapse" id="mybox">
                            Lorem ipsum ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-content{
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You have to wrap your content in .collapse and if you want to have padding, you can set CSS of your wrapper.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="box-content collapse" id="mybox">
  <div class='wrapper'>                  
    Lorem ipsum ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I've wrapped the button instead of content and it works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Easy - just add another div inside the collapse one which has the styling

Comment: isn't actually working for me, alas. Still get the jump.

Comment: it doesn't work if you use the `.collapse` class for referencing the inner div in your stylesheet because the `collapse` class will get changed to `collapsing` during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the HTML structure, add these styles:

```
/* Override bootstrap collapse to keep margins */
.collapse.in {
  display: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapse {
  display: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Bootstrap sets display to none when the animation finishes, which removes the entire div, including the padding. Setting visibility to hidden does not remove the div, but it's height is 0, so all is left is the padding.

Make sure these styles are defined *after* the bootstrap stylesheet.